# How can i get method be called between method in java?

Tags: java, methods, relationship

As in the following example, I can get method1's signature by `Class.getFields()`,  but I want to get more information about methodA,B,C be called in `method1`

I want to get relationship between methods in Java.

```
public void method1(){
   call methodA
   call methodB
   .......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with reflection. If you're not dealing with source code, then you'd need to do bytecode analysis. If you're dealing with source code, you could probably use some dependency injection/tracking tool. Actually, some of those can probably work directly on bytecode as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  actually i want to analyze source code in jave,